# What is this semicircle-like shape called?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I would like to know the name of the shape shown below

[image]

I know that the shape without the straight part at the bottom between the two quarter circles is called a *semicircle*. Also this shape vaguely resembles the shape of a halfpipe, but I am quite sure that is not the mathematically correct name for it.

Who knows what this shape is called? Or whether it has a specific name at all?

Comment: I would call it probably 'dish shape'..

Comment: "Two quarter circles connected by horizontal lines." For a fancier name, one could probably call it a rounded trapezoid.

Comment: As far as I know, it has no name, as such. Note that it consists of a rectangle and (presumably) two quarter circles of equal radius.

Comment: @Semiclassical As far as I know, rounded trapezoids are something else entirely.

Comment: @ABajaj: Yeah, Google agrees with you; i was trying to come up with a name on the spot. (I also thought of 'circular trapezoid, but that's definitely taken.) I really doubt there's a canonical answer.

Comment: Half a [stadium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stadium_%28geometry%29)?

Comment: @Rahul: I'd call it a semi-stadium except that it's not clear which axis one cuts along. (Maybe a major v. minor semi-stadium?)

Comment: @Semiclassical cutting the major axis of the stadium would result in what is often called an extended or elongated semicircle, so perhaps semi-stadium is not that bad?!

Comment: Here's a hint: draw two circles above your shape, one to the left, and the other to the right, then encompass all three objects inside a greater circle. The answer will soon come to you. :-)

Comment: @Lucian Smiley?!

Comment: Precisely! In which case, the official name of your shape should be *grin*. :-) Or *boat*.